# Where Nautilus/Gnome keeps track or log of user activity?

Tags: linux, gnome, nautilus

Today I came across a file called `~user/.nautilus/saved-session-XXXXXX`. In it one could see some sort of logging user's activity via Nautilus. Also in `~user/.gconf/apps/gedit-2` one could find interesting things.

Is there a file where Nautilus tracks user's activity?  Is there a file which states files accessed, moved, copied, deleted, etc. via Nautilus?

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus keeps a history of directories visited which is accessible through it's history menu or panel.

It does not appear to keep the kind of records you are looking for. If you need this kind of security auditing you should consider setting up a file system that logs these kind of changes or allows snapshoting so you can make your own comparisons.

Answer (score -1):

After a pause of work, open nautilus, work something, and then:

```
find ~user/.gconf -mmin -10 -ls
find ~user/.nautilus -mmin -10 -ls
```

which will find files, modified in the last 10 minutes.

Comment: 1) `~user` is a common and shell recognized notation for a users folder, particularly in scripts that might not be run by that user. It can be abbreviated `~` to refer to the current user. 2) On many systems it could be quite difficult to sort through the noise in order to find what you are looking for with the method you suggest. It would be more helpful if you found the answer on your own control system.

Comment: If you don't do much for 10 minutes, you won't have that much noise. And you may restrict the search to 2 or 1 minute, if you act fast enough. Thanks for the hint to ~user, I didn't knew that one, it even works on ubuntu. :)